# C++ mathematical problem and 5/4*pi vs 5*pi/4

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, math, visual-c++

```
#define M_PI acos(-1.0)

int main()
{
    double z1 = sin(M_PI / 2 + 3 * x) / (1 - sin(3 * x - M_PI));
    double z2 = 1 / tan(5 * M_PI / 4 + 3 * x / 2);  // line 14
    double z3 = 1 / tan(5 / 4 * M_PI + 3 * x / 2);  // line 15

    printf("%lf, %lf, %lf, z1, z2, z3);
}
```

So as you can see in 14 and 15 lines we have really similar expressions. So why do we get different results?

Comment: Please post your code in the question and not with a screenshot.

Comment: Put the code in the question, leave out the image

Comment: This would be a nice question if the picture was replaced by code. What I don't understand is why it's considered quicker these days to take a picture of the screen and paste it as an image, rather than a copy and paste into the question editor!

Comment: Because `5/4 == 1` but `5./4 == 1.25`.

Comment: btw if you want to force floating point then you can rewrite to `5.0 * M_PI / 4.0` or `5.0 / 4.0 * M_PI` but even those can lead to slightly different results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because both the following operations are different :

```
5 * M_PI / 4
```

and

```
5 / 4 * M_PI
```

The operations are performed left to right.

On the first line, 5 * M_PI (int * float) returns a float (15.7...) which is divided by an int (float / int) returning a float (3.9...).

On the second line, 5 / 4 returns an int (int / int) equal to 1, then multiplied by M_PI (int * float) returning a float, which returns exactly M_PI (3.14...)

Which are different results.

Comment: Not necessarily performed, but merely grouped.

Comment: Well they are performed at some point after the start of compilation and before the end of execution.

Answer (score 6):

`5 / 4 * M_PI` is grouped as `(5 / 4) * M_PI` with the `5 / 4` being evaluated in integer arithmetic, which is `1`.

Writing it the other way forces conversion of the other coefficients to floating point.

(As a final point, the flashy definition `#define M_PI acos(-1.0)` is not guaranteed by any common floating point scheme - including IEEE754 - to recover the mathematical value of pi within the accuracy permitted by the floating point type on your platform. It's best written out longhand.)

Answer (score 0):

Since `/` and `*` have the same operator precedence, the evaluation of the expression depends on the associativity. Associativity indicates in what order operators of equal precedence in an expression are applied. Here associativity is left-to-right. See [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) table.

So `5 / 4 * M_PI` **is** `(5 / 4) * M_PI` and `(5 / 4)` is integer division and evaluates to 1.
Whereas `5 * M_PI / 4` **is** `(5 * M_PI) / 4` and this results in floating point division as `5 * M_PI` is a floating point value.